# Python Error on FBX Import

Tags: python

so I'm making a plane for Roblox (I know stupid right) But I keep getting this line of errors:

```sh
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py", line 636, in execute
    return export_fbx_bin.save(self, context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3198, in save
    ret = save_single(operator, context.scene, depsgraph, filepath, **kwargs_mod)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3094, in save_single
    fbx_objects_elements(root, scene_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 2894, in fbx_objects_elements
    fbx_data_mesh_elements(objects, me_obj, scene_data, done_meshes)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1174, in fbx_data_mesh_elements
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv, t_lvidx)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\fbx_utils.py", line 504, in elem_data_single_int32_array
    return _elem_data_single(elem, name, value, "add_int32_array")
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\fbx_utils.py", line 451, in _elem_data_single
    getattr(sub_elem, func_name)(value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\encode_bin.py", line 161, in add_int32_array
    data = array.array(data_types.ARRAY_INT32, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1174, in <genexpr>
    elem_data_single_int32_array(lay_uv, b"UVIndex", (uv2idx[uv_id] for uv_id in _uvtuples_gen(t_luv, t_lvidx)))
KeyError: ((nan, nan), 6)

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you still get the error if you update blender to the [2.93 LTS](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/2-93/) version? If so, I'd consider reporting it as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it still gives the same problem. I will report it as a bug.